# One-time password verification

Tags: javascript, react.js

I've built a small OTP code verification component and I need reviews and suggestion to improve its performance and maybe the logic behind it. The purpose is to publish my first 'react component' to npm in order to be reusable by the open source community.

Feel free to share the best practices.

````
import { createRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
const DEFAULT_DIGIT_COUNT = 6;
/**
 * NOTE: The following implementation is not clean and incomplet.

 * OTP verfification app is a set of digit inputs that validate a sent code
 * Input: 6 digits of separated inputs
 * Verification: strict equal with the security code
 * Output: Success/Fail of verification
 * Security: Server Side verification
 * Workflow:
 * When all the inputs are validated , send the code to verify it in the server
 * if Ok => success Callback; else a failure callback
 */

function App() {
  console.log("render");
  const [isGoodCode, setIsGoodCode] = useState(false);
  const verificationCode = "152301";

  const [digits, setDigits] = useState(Array(DEFAULT_DIGIT_COUNT).fill(""));
  const [activeDigit, setActiveDigit] = useState(0);
  const digitInuputs = digits.map((digit) => {
    return { value: digit, ref: createRef() };
  });
  const handleOnSetDigit = (e, index) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    if (value > 9 || value < 0) return;
    let dArray = [...digits];
    dArray[index] = value;
    setDigits(dArray);
    if (digitInuputs[index + 1] && value) {
      console.log(digitInuputs[index + 1].ref);
      digitInuputs[index + 1].ref.current.focus();
      setActiveDigit(index + 1);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (e) => {
      if (e.key === "Tab") {
        console.log(digits[activeDigit]);
        const firstEmptyDigitInput = digits.findIndex((d) => d === "");
        if (digitInuputs[firstEmptyDigitInput]) {
          digitInuputs[firstEmptyDigitInput].ref.current.focus();
          return;
        }
        if (!digits[activeDigit]) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
      }
      if (e.key === "Backspace") {
        if (digitInuputs[activeDigit - 1]) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let dArray = [...digits];
          dArray[activeDigit] = "";
          console.log(digitInuputs[activeDigit - 1].ref);
          digitInuputs[activeDigit - 1].ref.current.focus();
          setActiveDigit(activeDigit - 1);
          setDigits(dArray);
        }
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (digits.join("") === verificationCode) setIsGoodCode(true);
    else setIsGoodCode(false);
  }, [digits]);

  return (
    <div className="digit-wrapper">
      <div>Status: {isGoodCode ? "Good" : "Bad"}</div>
      {digitInuputs.map((d, index) => (
        <div className="digit-input">
          <input
            type="number"
            value={Number.parseInt(d.value)}
            onChange={(e) => handleOnSetDigit(e, index)}
            ref={d.ref}
            max={"9"}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Your code is vulnerable to a [*side-channel attack*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack), more precisely, a [*timing attack*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) on the [*string comparison*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/94579/2139).

The problem is here:

```ecmascript
if (digits.join("") === verificationCode) setIsGoodCode(true);
else setIsGoodCode(false);
```

In all real-world implementations of ECMAScript, string comparison will be optimized to return `false` as soon as a character does not match, i.e. it will be implemented something like this:

```ecmascript
function stringEquals(a, b) {
  const length = a.length;

  if (length !== b.length) return false;

  for (let idx = 0; idx < length; idx++)
    if (a[idx] !== b[idx]) return false;

  return true;
}
```

However, this leaks information about the prefix of the string: if I try to brute-force the OTP, it will take longer to reject a wrong OTP if I have guessed the beginning correctly. This means I can guess each digit separately, instead of having to guess the whole number which reduces the effort for a brute-force attack from 10<sup>6</sup> to 10×6, i.e. from one million to sixty … almost twenty-thousand times faster.

I can simply try to log in with `000000`, `100000`, `200000`, `300000`, `400000`, `500000`, `600000`, `700000`, `800000`, and `900000`, and one of them will take slightly longer to reject me: then I know that I have guessed the first number correctly, and I can repeat that same exercise with the second number, and so on.

When writing cryptographic code, you have to make sure to write your code in such a way that the execution time does not depend on *secret data*. (This is called *constant-time* which is somewhat confusing because it has nothing to do with the notion of *constant-time*, i.e. O(1) in algorithmic complexity theory. I will called it *fixed-time*.)

In cryptographic code, it is important that all operations are *fixed-time*. More precisely, *all resource usage* (time is only one kind of resource that can be measured by an attacker, another example is energy) must be *independent of the secret data* (it is okay to depend on data supplied by the attacker; after all, the attacker knows their own data, so leaking information about it doesn't hurt).

A *fixed-time* string comparison might look something like this, (ab)using bit-wise OR and bit-wise XOR of the individual character's numeric values:

```ecmascript
function stringEquals(a, b) {
  const length = a.length;

  // Suggested by Alex in a comment below.
  // Note: both the old and the new version assume that
  // `String.prototype.length` is constant-time.
  let difference = length - b.length;

  for (let idx = 0; idx < length; idx++)
    difference |= (a.charCodeAt(idx) ^ b.charCodeAt(idx));

  return 0 === difference;
}
```

But note that a clever enough compiler / optimizer might still perform optimizations that introduce timing dependencies again, so you will have to inspect the generated assembly code. And even then, you still don't know how the CPU executes the code, so you have to carefully study the CPU's data sheets as well.

See here for some further information:

- [*How can I prevent side-channel attacks against authentication?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/220488/2139) on [Information Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/)
- [*How can I understand whether my C implementation is constant-time or not (i.e. resistant to timing attacks)*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/96614/17895) on [Cryptography.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)
- [*How to compare strings in constant time?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44691363/2988) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- [*Constant Time String Comparison in C*](https://nachtimwald.com/2017/04/02/constant-time-string-comparison-in-c/)
- [*“Constant Time” Compare in Python*](https://securitypitfalls.wordpress.com/2018/08/03/constant-time-compare-in-python/)
- [*A beginner's guide to constant-time cryptography*](https://chosenplaintext.ca/articles/beginners-guide-constant-time-cryptography.html)
- [*BearSSL – Why Constant-Time Crypto?*](https://bearssl.org/constanttime.html)
- [*Can I prevent timing attacks with random delays?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/96493/2139) on Information Security.SE
  [Spoiler alert: [No, you can't](https://fahrplan.events.ccc.de/congress/2012/Fahrplan/attachments/2235_29c3-schinzel.pdf). Random delays just add statistical noise, which can be filtered out.]
- [*A Note On Side-Channels Resulting From Dynamic Compilation*, D. Page](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/349.pdf)
  [Spoiler alert: dynamic optimizations such as the ones employed by all modern ECMAScript engines, JVMs, .NET, etc. can introduce side-channels or at least make it impossible to mitigate them.]

Now, in your specific case, this problem is actually easy to fix: why don't you just compare the two numbers as … numbers? Comparison of two small numbers should be fixed-time, although you have to careful about what "small" means. For example, there are 8-bit microcontrollers where the native `int` datatype is 16 bit wide, and they *do* short-circuit if the first 8 bits are already unequal.

Change

```ecmascript
const verificationCode = "152301";
```

to

```ecmascript
const verificationCode = 152301;
```

and change

```ecmascript
if (digits.join("") === verificationCode) setIsGoodCode(true);
else setIsGoodCode(false);
```

to

```ecmascript
const otp = parseInt(digits.join(""), 10);
if (otp === verificationCode) setIsGoodCode(true);
else setIsGoodCode(false);
```

Note: I am not very familiar with React, so I don't 100% follow why you even have an array of strings instead of a number in the first place. A better solution would be to make sure you always have a number to begin with, then you don't need all this joining and parsing.

Comment: Perfect ! thanks for sharing

Comment: What would be the consequence of not throwing `RangeError`? I noticed if I remove the length check and replace `let difference = 0;` with `let difference = length - b.length;`, the code still works. [Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpao4vys/). Thanks.

Comment: @Alex: I can't see any problems with that off the top of my hat. Thanks. My initial feeling was that there would be a problem with strings that differ only in the amount of trailing `NUL`s (because `NaN ^ 0` and `0 ^ NaN` are `0`), but of course if the strings are different length, the `difference` will already be non-zero to begin with.